# AJAX call not working on IE 11

Tags: javascript, ajax

This code of mine is working fine in the eclipse internal browser but it won't execute in IE 11 .Can anyone tell me why? I know this is a pretty old way of doing it, but I am not an expert in JS and can't make sense of the other method with JSON.

```
var request;

function sendInfo() {
    var v = document.abc.crd.value;;
    var url = "testjsp.jsp?val=" + v;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    try {
        request.onreadystatechange = getInfo;
        request.open("POST", url, true);
        request.send();
    }
    catch(e){
        alert("Unable to connect to server");
    }
}

function getInfo(){
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        var val = request.responseText;
        complete: function() {
            document.getElementById('disp_span').innerHTML = val;
        }
        document.getElementById('disp_span').innerHTML = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors does IE11 give in the developer tools (hit F12)?

Comment: Look at note section below in this link: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx` you can use `XMLHttpRequest` for IE11 as well. (`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx`)